# Identifiying Exponential value in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal, exponential

I am integrating a library with my c# code. There is a decimal parameter i am using from the library. Parameter return usual decimal values mostly like: 0.24756400. But sometimes it returns values in Exponential format like: 0E-8.

When i try process the parameter in my code, for example when i parse it like this:

```
Decimal.Parse(paymentAuth.IyziCommissionFee);)
```

it gives me exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object) when the value is in Exponential format.

If i can identify the value format (number or Exponential number) i can manage it.

So how can i identify if the value is in Exponential format? Alternatively, any suggestion to manage such situation?

Comment: This seems not right. This exception is probably thrown when  `paymentAuth` is `null`, not depending of the format.

Comment: The indicated error is not a parse error, you need to provide more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

## You don't need to identify if it is an exponent or not

If you want to parse a string that could be an exponential format into a decimal you can use the overload of the `Decimal.Parse` method that takes a `System.Globalization.NumberStyles` parameter to do this.

```
var result = Decimal.Parse(
              paymentAuth.IyziCommissionFee,
              System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float
            );
```

This specifies that the incoming string is a float, which you can represent using the exponential format you're talking about.

You can read the MSDN docs about this overload and the `NumberStyles` type here :

- [Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Globalization.NumberStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)